# Show registration date in PHP

Tags: php

How would I show the registration date of a user? For example, it might say "User since: 3rd April 2015". What PHP code would I need to use to show this?

Comment: A database storing users and the date they registered. Then query DB and output result.

Comment: The database I have should store the date registered, but how do I show the dates?

Comment: Run a query to get the date, `select date_registered from users where userid = ?` Then fetch and return the result `echo $row['date_registered'];`. For more specifics please post the code you've written and the issue you're encountering.

Comment: How did this question got an upV? It shows no effort and no research!

Answer (score 2):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php);

```
$myDate = date("jS M Y");
echo "User since: $myDate";
```

---

Output:

```
User since: 3rd May 2015
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/BzzoxP

---

Explanation:

`j` Day of the month without leading zeros 1 to 31
`S` English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters st, nd, rd or th. Works well with `j`
`M` A short textual representation of a month, three letters Jan through Dec
`Y` A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits Examples: 1999 or 2003

---

Comment: With date() 2nd arg, it would be nice :p